# Laravel 5.4 query builder and MySQL functions

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I'm building query using Laravel query builder and I'm having an issue with MySQL functions.

I have a Mysql functions that receives the `user_id` and some other paramenters to calculate a user's score. This query must return only users with score above a certain value. The query is giant, so I'm pasting only the part that is causing be trouble:

```
$query = $query->where(DB::raw($fstr.' >= 70'));
```

Generates this :

```
AND f_user_matching_score(4, admin__user.id_user, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ',') >= 70 IS NULL
```

This:

```
$query = $query->where($fstr,'>=',  70));
```

Generates this:

```
AND `f_user_matching_score(4, admin__user.id_user, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, ',')` >= 70
```

Both are invalid. The first is adding this `IS NULL` and the second the back ticks.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Try `whereRaw` instead. `$query->whereRaw($fstr.' >= 70');`

Comment: @aynber Perfect, it worked. Thanks. Please post an answer so I can give you the points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `whereRaw()` for fully raw where queries. This way it will not expect any other variables being passed in, though you can if need be.

```
$query->whereRaw($fstr.' >= 70');
```

If you needed to pass in variables for quoting, you'd just pass them in as an array:

```
$query->whereRaw("f_user_matching_score(?, admin__user.id_user, ?, ?, ?, 0, 0, ?) >= 70", [4, 1, 0, 0, ',']);
```